# How to use callback function with dll

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I'm using Visual C++ and i want to link a dll file created on Delphi. Function params from there are using callback. I'm trying to use my callback function in dll function.

```
typedef void(__stdcall *Cypress_Init)(int width, int height, void(__stdcall TCypCallbackFoo)(WORD* pData, int Reason));


void (__stdcall TCypCallbackFoo)(WORD* pData, int Reason)
{
    cout << "Enter callback function" << endl;
    cout << "Reason: " << Reason << endl;
}

int main()
{   
    DWORD err;
    HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)L"c:\\Libs\\Cypress143200.dll"); // dll.dll - название подключаемой библиотеки
    if (hDll != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Library was loaded" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }

    Cypress_Init cypInit = (Cypress_Init) GetProcAddress(hDll, "Cypress_Init");
    if (cypInit != NULL)
    {
        (*cypInit)(640, 480, TCypCallbackFoo);
        cout << "good" << endl;
    }
 }
```

So the result of this

```
>  Library was loaded
>  good
```

This means that I'm using it correctly, but there is no callback function call. I'm expecting output something like this

```
 >  Library was loaded
 >  good
 >  Enter callback function
 >  Reason: 1
```

But this does not happen... Please show to me my mistake in using the callback function?

---

Code header of dll functuon on delphi below

```
unit UCypA;

interface

const
  libname = 'Cypress143200.dll';

type
  TCypCallback = procedure(pData: Pointer; Reason: Integer); stdcall;

  procedure Cypress_Init(AWidth, AHeight: Integer; Callback: TCypCallback); stdcall; external libname;

implementation

end.
```

Example of DLL usage in Delphi(it works):

```
procedure CypCallback(pData: Pointer; Reason: Integer); stdcall;
begin
 case Reason of
   CYP_NEWCADR: Form1.Newcadr(pData);
   CYP_ATTACH: Form1.Caption := 'Attach';
   CYP_DETACH:Form1.Caption := 'Detach';
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Cypress_Init(640, 480, @CypCallback);
end;

procedure TForm1.NewCadr(Data: Pointer);
var
  pw: PWordArray;
begin
  pw := PWordArray(Data);
  //work with data
end;
```

Comment: Everything looks fine in terms of the interop. The likely explanation is that your calling program terminates before the DLL has a chance to call your callback function. Do you know when the callback is called? Is it in response to another call to the library. Do you have example Delphi code that consumes the library?

Comment: *Do you know when the callback is called? Is it in response to another call to the library?* It's not likely to be called when the thread is in an infinite loop. How can it be called then, the thread is busy with your loop.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Please take a bit more time to digest what I said and come back with edits to the question.

Comment: The difference in the Delphi code is that it is a GUI application that pumps the message queue. Perhaps that's what gets the callback called. Or perhaps there is more that we cannot see. We don't have any documentation, and frankly it looks like you are doing this with trial and error.

Comment: Thanks, David. Your arguments pushed me into the right direction. The loop which was awaiting response was wrong, and thread was busy. Make you comment as an answer and i'll accept it.